# Java console output - File And to Console BOTH

Tags: java, outputstream

Probably this thread is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749431/is-there-a-way-to-output-to-both-a-file-and-the-console) but can someone guide? I want to write the java program output to **console** and **file** at the same time. I know that i can send output to console with this piece of code

```
    PrintStream orgStdout = null;
    PrintStream fileStdout = null;

    orgStdout = System.out;
    try {
        fileStdout = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\testlogger.txt"));
        System.setOut(fileStdout);
        System.out.println("==============");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println("" + i);
        }
        System.out.println("==============");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but how to keep output on console and on file as well??

P.S:
not looking for an option where i output in file and display it console in different thread.

Comment: Should look into [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Answer (score 7):

Look for `TeeOutputStream` from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html).

Comment: There is no `TeeOutputStream` on that page.

Comment: Fixed with Apache Commons IO JavaDoc link.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call System.setOut(), and just make two calls to print.  It's not very elegant, but you could make a method that outputs to both.

```
PrintStream orgStdout = null;
PrintStream fileStdout = null;

orgStdout = System.out;
try {
    fileStdout = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\testlogger.txt"));
    System.out.println("==============");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("" + i);
        fileStdout.println("" + i);
    }
    System.out.println("==============");
    fileStdout.println("" + i);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you're running on a unix box, you could also use the `tee` command as long as everything is printed to stdout.  You'd run your program like this:

```
java MyClass | tee testlogger.txt
```

Then everything printed to stdout goes to both the file and console.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program

```
java {flags to the JVM} ClassName {parameters to your class} > output.txt 2> error.txt
```